# dataIKU seaborn module not recongnized

Tags: seaborn, dataiku

```
!pip list
Package         Version
--------------- -----------------
contourpy       1.2.0
cycler          0.12.1
fonttools       4.47.0
kiwisolver      1.4.5
matplotlib      3.8.2
notebook        5.7.16-dku-12.2-0
numpy           1.26.2
packaging       23.2
pandas          2.1.4
Pillow          10.1.0
pip             23.3.2
pyparsing       3.1.1
pyspark         3.4.1
python-dateutil 2.8.2
pytz            2023.3.post1
seaborn         0.13.0
setuptools      69.0.2
six             1.16.0
tzdata          2023.3

pip show 0.13.0
WARNING: Package(s) not found: 0.13.0
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.

seaborn packae is installed in dataIKU but not recognized
```

.